# What is the alternative for iterrows in polars python?

Tags: python, python-polars

I want to detect rows with null values when they are mandatory. The column `mandatory` gives information about this. If the value `"M"` occurs, the row is mandatory. If this is the case, this row should be checked for null values. If there is at least one null value, this row should be reported. First I tried it with Python and pandas. Finally I wanted to try it with Polars and failed because of iterrows. Therefore I have the question how can I translate this code into polars?

```
from typing import List
import pandas as pd

def detect_infringements(self, df):
    report = []
    df = df[df["mandatory"] == "M"]
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row.isnull().sum() > 0:
            report.append({"Index": index, "Warning": "Infringement detected"})
    return report
```

Here is the polars df:

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
        'ID': ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],
        'Entity': ['Entity 1', 'Entity 2', 'Entity 3', 'Entity 4', 'Entity 5'],
        'Table': ['Table 1', 'Table 2', 'Table 3', 'Table 4', None],
        'Local': ['Local 1', 'Local 2', None, 'Local 4', 'Local 5'],
        'Global': ['Global 1', 'Global 2', 'Global 3', None, 'Global 5'],
        'mandatory': ['M', 'M', 'M', 'CM', 'M']
    })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `.filter`:

```py
In [26]: df.filter(pl.any(pl.col('*').is_null()) & pl.col('mandatory').eq('M'))
Out[26]:
shape: (2, 6)
┌─────┬──────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬───────────┐
│ ID  ┆ Entity   ┆ Table   ┆ Local   ┆ Global   ┆ mandatory │
│ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---      ┆ ---       │
│ str ┆ str      ┆ str     ┆ str     ┆ str      ┆ str       │
╞═════╪══════════╪═════════╪═════════╪══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 3   ┆ Entity 3 ┆ Table 3 ┆ null    ┆ Global 3 ┆ M         │
│ 5   ┆ Entity 5 ┆ null    ┆ Local 5 ┆ Global 5 ┆ M         │
└─────┴──────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴───────────┘
```

To get the row list:

```py
(
    df.with_row_count("Index")
    .filter(pl.any(pl.col("*").is_null()) & pl.col("mandatory").eq("M"))
    .with_columns(pl.lit("Infringement detected").alias("Warning"))
    .select(["Index", "Warning"])
    .to_dicts()
)
```

```
Out[26]:
[{'Index': 2, 'Warning': 'Infringement detected'},
 {'Index': 4, 'Warning': 'Infringement detected'}]
```

Comment: Nice thank you. But afterwards I want to return also a list of infringements in a report. It should contain the row values as which are filtered as dictionaries.

Comment: @Horseman I've updated, does this work for you?

Comment: I would think ID would be better than the `with_row_count` index for anything meaningful but that's OP's problem not a problem with the answer since that's what they asked for.  Nice answer, I like it. Perhaps in their pandas implementation the index is something meaningful so something to look into for them.

Comment: yeah good point, I was trying to match the output from the pandas code, but realistically you're right, they probably want `'ID'` instead of `'index'`. Anyway, I hope this answer gives them the tools they need to adapt it to their own problem

Comment: @ignoring_gravity that's why Enterprise is so great, they give you the tools to be your own boss.